# Jquery validation and TinyMCE 4.0.1

Tags: jquery, validation, tinymce

Since I updated to TinyMCE Version 4.0.1 my Jquery Validation does not longer working. In Version 3.x, the script works without problems. Can I use the onchange_callback function at all ...?

Has anyone had an idea or the same problem before?

My TinyMCE Config:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    language : "de",      
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "modern",
    height: 250,

    statusbar : false,
    relative_urls : false,


    // update validation status on change
    onchange_callback: function(editor) {
        tinyMCE.triggerSave();          
        $("#" + editor.id).valid();     
    },

    // Theme options        
    ...

</script>
```

My Validation Code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // update underlying textarea before submit validation          
        tinyMCE.triggerSave();

    ...
    ...

validator.focusInvalid = function() {
        // put focus on tinymce on submit validation    
        if( this.settings.focusInvalid ) {
            try {
                var toFocus = $(this.findLastActive() || this.errorList.length && this.errorList[0].element || []);
                if (toFocus.is("textarea")) {
                    tinyMCE.get(toFocus.attr("id")).focus();
                } else {
                    toFocus.filter(":visible").focus();
                }               
            } catch(e) {
            }           
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Changes in tinyMCE 4 are detected with the config

```
tinymce.init({
    ...
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('change', function(e) {
            console.log('change event', e);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are also faced this problem means required validation is not working when you are using tinymce html editor, so i have one solution, please follow it and i hope your problem  solve, Check below code 
install package of tinymce jquery in your application with the use of nuget package
create one model like this
**Model**

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter About Company")]
    [Display(Name = "About Company : ")]
    [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
    public string txtAboutCompany { get; set; }
```

**CSHTML OR VIEW**

```
 <div class="divclass">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.txtAboutCompany, new { @class = "required" })
       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.txtAboutCompany)
       <span class="field-validation-error" id="AC" style="margin:9px 0 0 57px;">/span>
 </div>
```

And this is jquery

```
$("#BusinessProfile").click(function () {
        var aboutC = $("#txtAboutCompany").val()
        var pinfo = $("#txtProductinfo").val();
        if (aboutC == "" && pinfo == "") {
            $("#AC").append("").val("").html("Please enter about company")
            $("#PI").append("").val("").html("Please enter product information")
            $("#bpform").valid();
            return false;
        } else if (aboutC == "") {
            $("#PI").append("").val("").html("")
            $("#AC").append("").val("").html("Please enter about company")
            $("#txtAboutCompany").focus();
            $("#bpform").valid();
            return false;
        } else if (pinfo == "") {
            $("#AC").append("").val("").html("")
            $("#PI").append("").val("").html("Please enter product information")
            $("#txtProductinfo").focus();
            $("#bpform").valid();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $("#AC").append("").val("").html("");
            $("#PI").append("").val("").html("");
            //return true;
            $("#bpform").validate();
        }
    });
```